# Load Related Entities With EF 5 Context.Database.SqlQuery

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have this SP,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetPageByID]
(
    @ID INT
)
AS

    SELECT  P.*
            ,A.*
    FROM    Page P
            LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Application] A ON P.ApplicationVersion = A.[Version]
    WHERE   P.ID = @ID;
```

and I am using this code to load into objects,

```
        return context.Database.SqlQuery<Page>(@"EXEC GetPageByID {0}", new object[] { id }).FirstOrDefault();
```

This only loads properties of Page but not loading Page.Application property. Any way to tell EF to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `SqlQuery` is able to load only the main entity you are asking for - in your case the `Page`. If you want to load children as well you cannot use `SqlQuery`. EF5 with EDMX provides mapping for [stored procedures with multiple result sets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/jj691402) (that means you will need stored procedure with two queries - one for pages and second for applications). It is not supported with code first yet.